# curl localhost to connect from one docker container to another docker container

Tags: docker, curl

I have following `docker-compose` and run it locally:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  testservice.api:
    image: testservice.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/.../Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5101:80"
  sql.data:
    image: postgres.jchem
    build:
      context: ../db/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
      - "9090:9090"
```

Now within the `sql.data` container I try to execute `curl http://localhost:5101/...`
But I get the exit code (7) Connect failed
When I try to connect via `curl http://testservice.api/...` it works.
Why can't I connect with `localhost:port`? And how can I accomplish to connect from within a docker container to another with `curl localhost:port`?

Comment: When you are "inside" a container, *localhost* refers to the container itself, not the host.

Comment: I thought from docker version 3 onwards all the containers automatically run in the same network?

Comment: same network is not the same as same as sharing the same network address, each container receives their own IP address in the virtual network.

Comment: How do I accomplish that I can access a container within another container with the same address as I use from the host (in this case localhost:5101)? How can I make the container translate localhost:5101 to testservice.api?

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I connect with localhost:port?

That's because each container gets its own network interface, hence its own 'localhost'.

> And how can I accomplish to connect from within a docker container to another with curl localhost:port?

What you can do is use `network_mode: "host"` in each compose service so every container use the same host net interface. Though, I recommend you to adapt your apps to be configurable so they get their service dependencies URLs as params (for example).

Comment: Inside the container, take a look at `/etc/hosts` assuming it's a Linux container, that might add some additional context

Answer (score 0):

When you say localhost in inside a container then it will read as the container itself. For a container to be able to communicate with other containers. You need to make sure that those containers are connected on the same network and then you can try accessing them via their DNS (their service name) or their container IP.